# Which .NET languages have syntactic support for extension methods?

Tags: .net, extension-methods

I've recently asked a [question about designing API that are mostly based on interfaces and extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11441905/240733).

Which made me wonder, are there .NET languages that don't directly support extension methods, i.e. languages where working with such an API would become a pain?

I'm aware that extension methods are simply static methods and can likely always be called as such, but with "support for extension methods" I mean a tighter integration into the language's syntax for calling methods on an object; the way extension methods can be used in C# as if they were regular methods.

Which of the more popular .NET languages besides C# and VB.NET actually support extension methods, and which don't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**F#** supports extension methods in recent versions (e.g. the version that ships with VS2010).
 See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/777254/240733) to the question, "Using extension methods defined in C# from F# code".

---

**PowerShell** [can be made to sort of support extension methods](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/09/06/extension-methods-in-windows-powershell.aspx) via the Extended Type System.

---

**IronPython** seems to support extension methods...

- [via some weird custom attribute prior to version 2.7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2008/11/14/consuming-extension-methods-in-ironpython.aspx) (?), and
- [via `clr.importExtensions()` starting with version 2.7](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/54498/).

---

**IronRuby**, [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5572802/240733) to the question, "IronRuby calling C# Extension Methods - Error - Compatibility in .NET 3.5", supports extension methods starting with version 1.4 (which requires .NET 4) via `using_clr_extensions`.

---

**IronScheme**: [does have extension methods](http://ironscheme.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ExtensionMethods), but I'm not entirely sure whether they are the same mechanism as extension methods in C# 3.

---

**Boo**, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4634022/240733) to the question  "How can i use Extension Methods in boo", supports extension methods starting from version 0.9.0.

---

**Nemerle** seems to support extension methods, too (according to [a page on its website](http://nemerle.org/wiki/index.php?title=Extension_methods)).

---

**Managed C++**: (*expanding on stakx's answer*) Managed C++ supports Extension Methods as you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012578/how-can-i-create-net-extension-methods-by-c-cli).

---

> *(Please feel free to expand and improve this answer!)*